# how to find the address stored in processor when doing an indirect jump in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering, att

I am trying to translate the assembly code into C code.

```
00000000004007e4 <f5>:
  4007e4:   48 83 ec 28             sub    $0x28,%rsp // 
  4007e8:   89 7c 24 0c             mov    %edi,0xc(%rsp) // a = i  0xcrsp = a
  4007ec:   83 7c 24 0c 05          cmpl   $0x5,0xc(%rsp) 
  4007f1:   77 6f                   ja     400862 <f5+0x7e> //else() a > 5
  4007f3:   8b 44 24 0c             mov    0xc(%rsp),%eax
  4007f7:   48 8b 04 c5 30 0a 40    mov    0x400a30(,%rax,8),%rax // 8a + 0x400a30
  4007fe:   00 
  4007ff:   ff e0                   jmpq   *%rax // jump to 8a + 0x400a30
  400801:   8b 44 24 0c             mov    0xc(%rsp),%eax 
  400805:   c1 e8 02                shr    $0x2,%eax // a >> 2
  400808:   89 44 24 1c             mov    %eax,0x1c(%rsp) 
  40080c:   eb 63                   jmp    400871 <f5+0x8d>
  40080e:   8b 44 24 0c             mov    0xc(%rsp),%eax
```

This is x86-64 AT&T syntax. The function has only one parameter. Here %edi is the parameter and I set 0xc(%rsp) to be variable a. In line 4007f7, it asks me to move 0x400a30 + 8a in to %rax and then jump to *rax. However, there is no command which has this number. I also used objdump to reach the data section but I still can't find valid address of command to jump to. How can I figure out where is this going to jump to?

Comment: Don't post your disassembly as an image. Paste the text into your question.

Comment: In theory there is a jump table starting at memory address `0x400a30` with 6 addresses (indexes 0  to 5). Each address should be 8 bytes long. you'd need to dump the bytes at `0x400a30`. Each 8 bytes should be a valid address to somewhere in memory.

Comment: There is a reasonable chance that such a jump table forms the basis of a _C_  `switch` statement. SO I'd probably expect the jump table to contain addresses of the nature 0x40#### .

Comment: at 4007f7 is a `mov`, not a `lea`. It accesses memory at the computed address.

Comment: If you breakpoint at `jmp rax` instruction, then the target address is stored in `rax` register already. From your dump it's impossible to say what it will be, as it is loaded (by previous `mov`) from memory at 0x400a30+8\*rax, which content is not shown.

Comment: Ah, the bomb again! :)

Comment: @Jester the `switch` is #2 or #3? Or #4 already? ... will he come here again with #6? so many questions... can't recall ever seeing the #1 ... must be really easy one.

Comment: @Jester: [Somebody set up us the bomb.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_your_base_are_belong_to_us) / You have no chance to survive make your time.